# Validate Sign In

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am new to web development and I am creating a login interface for a Wi-Fi HotSpot at my university. I used bootstrap for the majority of the design and just implemented a simple form for username and password submission. However, before a user can login to the wireless hotspot they must agree to the terms & conditions checkbox each time. This is what I need validated on the login interface.

What they requested is that if the user tries to login without checking the box, that an error message popups telling the user to agree to the terms & conditions. You can see a live demo of my code here:

http://ece.uprm.edu/~s103924/Login%20Interface/test.html

I have no idea on where to begin with but have read that using javascript should be fairly simple to validate the form. Here is a copy of the source code so far:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sign in &middot; ECENET Wireless Internet</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oranienbaum' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        padding-top: 40px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
      }

      .form-signin {
        max-width: 350px;
        padding: 19px 29px 45px;
        margin: 0 auto 20px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 2px solid #e5e5e5;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
           -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
           -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
                box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
      }
      .form-signin .form-signin-heading,
      .form-signin .checkbox {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
      .form-signin input[type="text"],
      .form-signin input[type="password"] {
        font-size: 16px;
        height: auto;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        padding: 7px 9px;
      }

    </style>
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>


    <div class="container">

     <form method="post" action="https://lanaccess.ece.uprm.edu:8001/" class="form-signin">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">ECENET Login</h2>
        <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Username" maxlength="15">
        <input type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password">
        <input name="redirurl" type="hidden" value="http://ece.uprm.edu">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input name="termsagree" type="checkbox" value="yes"> I Agree to the <a data-toggle="modal" href="#example">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
        </label>
        <button name="accept" class="btn pull-right btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        <!--<p><a data-toggle="modal" href="#example" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Terms & Conditions</a></p>-->
      </form>

    <div id="example" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none; ">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
              <h3>T&eacute;rminos &amp; Condiciones:</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <h4>A Todos Los Usuarios:</h4>
              <p><ol>
      <li>
        La Junta de Sindicos de la Universidad de Puerto Rico, mediante Certificacion Numero 072, Serie 1999-2000 aprobo la Politica Institucional y Procedimiento Para el Uso Etico Legal de las Tecnologias de Informacion de la Universidad de Puerto Rico.</li>
      <p>
      <li>
        Las disposiciones contenidas en esta politica son de aplicacion a toda la comunidad universitaria, clientes externos, las personas que presten servicios, asi como a todos los usuarios de los recursos de tecnologias de informacion y servicios de telecomunicaciones.</li>
      <p>
      <li>
        Toda vez que el acceso a las redes y al ambiente de las tecnologias de informacion es un privilegio institucional que otorga la Universidad de Puerto Rico, todos los usuarios tienen la responsabilidad de usar estos recursos de una manera eficiente y efectiva, observando estrictamente todas las normas eticas y legales contenidas en los estatutos estatales, federales, asi como en los reglamentos, politicas y procedimientos de la Universidad.</li>
      <p>
      <li>
        Cualquier violacion a las disposiciones contenidas en esta politica por parte de algun usuario, sera causa suficiente para iniciar un proceso de accion disciplinaria en su contra; incluyendo la no asignacion de los recursos y/o accesos, expulsion, despido o cualquier otra accion legal disponible.</li>
      <p>
      <li>
        Las politicas referentes a los recursos de tecnologia de informacion estan disponibles en <a href="http://www.uprm.edu/politicas" target="_blank">http://www.uprm.edu/politicas</a></li>
    </ol></p>            
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
            </div>
          </div>


    </div> <!-- /container -->

    <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated. At least on ideas of where to look or tutorials online that address my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you do.. Change you  tag to run validation function onSubmit..

```
<form method="post" action="https://lanaccess.ece.uprm.edu:8001/" onsubmit="return validateForm()"  class="form-signin">

function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms[0]["termsagree"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("You must first agree to terms and conditions");
  return false;
  }
}
```

You many need to play with the validateForm function... Remember if you return false then form will not submit.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check whether the checkbox is checked or not when the user submit the form

I forgot adding the message...

```
$('.form-signin').on('submit', function(e) {
  if (!$(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked')){
    alert('You must agree with Terms and Conditions to Sign In');
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For a single checkbox you could get that value and check on it:

change `<input name="termsagree" type="checkbox" value="yes">` into:

```
<input id="termsagree" name="termsagree" type="checkbox" value="yes">
```

and then check it in script:

```
if (! document.getElementById('termsagree').checked) {
  alert("You have to agree to the Terms&Conditions");
}
```

For more complex validation [look here](http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml).

Comment: I tried your implementation but do I have to change something else for this to work? I made the changes you specified for the checkbox and I also added this:                                          <script type="text/javascript">
          if (! document.getElementById('termsagree').checked) {
          alert("You have to agree to the Terms&Conditions");
          }
after defining my form. But still allows me to submit the form

Comment: You have to set the onsubmit attribute in the form, like onsubmit="javascript:return validate();". And also encapsulate the check in a function.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again for your input. After a few tries with the above answers I just couldn't understand well what I needed to do. I took the online course from w3Schools and finally understood your answers. I decided to post what I did in case someone needs this.

1. I created a function to validate the form like this:

   function validateForm()
     {
       var x=document.forms["signin"]["termsagree"].checked;
       if (x==null || x=="")
       {
           alert("You must agree to the Terms & Conditions!");
           return false;
       }
     }

Then I changed the form to this:

```
<form form name="signin" method="post" action="https://lanaccess.ece.uprm.edu:8001/" onsubmit="return validateForm()"  class="form-signin">
```

Thats pretty much it.

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp

Thanks!